# STL set not sorted as expected

Tags: c++, stl

I have a class which contains members `A`, `B`, and `C`, and I want objects of this class stored in a `set`, where the ABC triplet is known to be unique, and should be the set key. However, the set ordering does not end up as expected.

My comparison functor is:

```
class MyClassLess {
public:
   bool operator() (const MyClass& t1, const MyClass& t2) const {
      if(t1.getA() < t2.getA())
         return true;
      if(t1.getB() < t2.getB())
         return true;
      return t1.getC() < t2.getC();
   }
};

typedef set<MyClass, MyClassLess> SetMyClass;
```

I expected elements in the set to be sorted first by `A`, and then by `B`, and finally by `C`. However, if I iterate through the set from `begin` to `end`, the sort order turns out to be:

1. B
2. C
3. A

In other words, I get a group of members which all have a specific value of `B`, and within that group I see all values of `C`, and for each value of `C` I then get all values of `A`.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Stop using a computer. Take out a pen and paper, and work out in detail whether your "ordering" makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comparison function is wrong. Here's a version that should work:

```
class MyClassLess {
public:
  bool operator()(const MyClass& t1, const MyClass& t2) const {
    if(t1.getA() < t2.getA())
      return true;
    if(t1.getA() > t2.getA())
      return false;
    if(t1.getB() < t2.getB())
      return true;
    if(t1.getB() > t2.getB())
      return false;
    return t1.getC() < t2.getC();
  }
};
```

You algorithm needs to return `false` the moment either `A` or `B` of the left side are smaller than the corresponding member on the right side.

Comment: Perhaps `std::tie(t1.getA(), t1.getB(), t1.getC()) < std::tie(t2.getA(), t2.getB(), t2.getC())`?

Comment: OK, done :-) I still hope that the real message is that it's important to understand the maths before one starts to write code...

Comment: @Kerrek: Done, too. You answer's message, though, is to know the right std lib feature and forget about the math. (Not that I would look down on that. If you use std lib algorithms rather than writing your own, you can't put bugs into them.)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a *correct* implementation of a comparison of a tuple of values, just use the comparison of standard-library tuples. You can create tuple of references using `std::tie`, so your comparator is simply:

```
#include <tuple>

// ...

bool operator() (const MyClass& t1, const MyClass& t2) const
{
    return std::tie(t1.getA(), t1.getB(), t1.getC())
         < std::tie(t2.getA(), t2.getB(), t2.getC());
}
```

However, you must still make sure what it actually *means* to compare a tuple of values. (Tip: Think "dictionary".)